# How can I make variables inside an IBAction public to all view controllers?

Tags: swift, xcode, variables, button, delegates

So I'm trying to make a Chess Time app, where both players have access to a clock and they change the time between bullet(3minutes), Blitz(5minutes), and Rapid(10Minutes). Well in my second view controller `SettingsController` I made 3 IBActions UIButtons for this.

```
   @IBAction func bulletPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
      
    var storedTime = bullet

    
    self.delegate?.storedTimeTimer()
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    
    }

@IBAction func blitzPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    var storedTime = blitz
}

@IBAction func rapidPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    var storedTime = rapid
    
    
    
}
```

This is my SettingsController, my whole point is trying to get the storedTime into the first controller. I tried to use a delegate, but I couldn't get it to work.

Here is the full First Controller:

```swift
    import UIKit

     class ChessTimer: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerTimer1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerTimer2: UILabel!
    
    var timer = Timer()
    var time = 10
    var isTimerRunning = false
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       if isTimerRunning == false {
           runTimer()
       }
        
        
     }

     @IBAction func restartButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        
        
        }
    
       @IBAction func pausePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        timer.invalidate()
       }
    
       @IBAction func settingsPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSettings", sender: self)
        
        }
    
           func runTimer() {
          timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,selector: 
      (#selector(ChessTimer.updateTimer)),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
           isTimerRunning = true
         }
    
         @objc func updateTimer() {
         if storedTime! < 1 {
             timer.invalidate()
            playerTimer1.text = "00:00"
            playerTimer2.text = "00:00"
         }
            else {
             storedTime! -= 1
        playerTimer1.text = prodTimeString(time: TimeInterval(storedTime)!)
        }
        
       }
    
       func prodTimeString(time: TimeInterval) -> String {
        let prodMinutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
        let prodSeconds = Int(time) % 60

        return String(format: "%02d:%02d", prodMinutes, prodSeconds)
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func playerButton1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func playerButton2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    }

       extension ChessTimer: SettingsControllerDelegate {
       func storedTimeTimer() {
        
       }
    
       }
```

This is the second full controller

```swift
        import UIKit

class SettingsController: UIViewController {
    
    
    var bullet = "03:00"
    var blitz = "05:00"
    var rapid = "10:00"
    var storedTime = 0
    var delegate: SettingsControllerDelegate?

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func bulletPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        var storedTime = bullet
    
        
        self.delegate?.storedTimeTimer()
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        
        }
    
    @IBAction func blitzPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        var storedTime = blitz
    }
    
    @IBAction func rapidPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        var storedTime = rapid    
    }
     }
      protocol SettingsControllerDelegate {
    
       func storedTimeTimer()
    
       }
```

Comment: I think before attempting this program, it would be good for you to understand the meaning of some basic concepts, like _variable scope_, and _MVVM pattern_. There are many swift tutorials that discuss both topics

Comment: I already know the MVC model, which I already use. I also do understand some concepts, I just not very sure about this specific detail. I'm not sure how to get this to one play to another. DO you have a better solution of how to label them?

Comment: If you had MVC, or better MVVM, you wouldn't store `var storedTime = 0` inside viewcontroller. And if you understood variable scope, you wouldn't redefine that variable in every method.
Basics are important. It's better to spend time on them now, when you are in the beginning of your program. Much harder to fix things later, and usually very hard to debug

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a `Constants.swift` file.

Click `File` -> `New` -> `File` -> `Swift File` and then name it `Constants.swift`.

In `Constants.swift`, declare `var storedTime = 0`.

**Delete** `var storedTime = 0` **from your view controllers**, **you'll only need it in Constants.swift**. (So **delete it from SettingsController**, etc.)

The `storedTime` variable will now be public to all view controllers.

Hope this helps someone!